# Is there any SIMPLE way to hide errors ONLY for anonymous users?

Tags: debugging, users

In almost all the times I searched for literature about disabling system errors\bad-notifications **ONLY** for anonymous/non-admin users, the result was large-scale discussions with seemingly pretty different answers involving honorable code changes. But me, I have yet to acquire serious knowledge in PHP... Is there really no **SIMPLE** solution out there for someone like me? One that will include an *external module* or *pasting a simple code snippet* in one of the TPL files?

I do not want to go to `admin/config/development/logging' and then click "none", because this option there cancels errors FOR ALL users, and not just for anonymous\non-admin ones.

Do you have such a simple, detailed explanation of how to do it?

This is a typical error message I would like to hide:

[image]

And here are some more details about it:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49905/the-website-encountered-an-unexpected-error-please-try-again-later)

Comment: That's a serious error. Nothing you can hide. You have to solve it. Go to  `/admin/reports/dblog` as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidently, there is a great answer in the question to [How can I hide a specific error in Drupal for everybody?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167370/can-i-hide-specific-errors-in-drupal) (not from me though) ... It starts with something like "Just open `template.php` and paste this cool snippet;"

I trust you know how to tweak it to make it fit for your case ... Especially this parts:

- change `phptemplate_` in the function name with your theme name.
- replace the test for `is_admin` to an equivalent test for "is user logged in" (aka is it NOT anonymous). Something like so:

  if(user_is_logged_in()){ print "Logged In"; }

The slightly adapted code to hide errors for anonymous users looks like so:

```
function phptemplate_status_messages($display = NULL) {
    $output = '';
    global $user;
    foreach (drupal_get_messages($display) as $type => $messages) {
      if (($type == 'error' && user_is_logged_in()) || $type != 'error') {
        $output .= "<div class="messages $type">\n";
        if (count($messages) > 1) {
          $output .= " <ul>\n";
          foreach ($messages as $message) {
            $output .= '  <li>'. $message ."</li>\n";
          }
          $output .= " </ul>\n";
        }
        else {
          $output .= $messages[0];
        }
        $output .= "</div>\n";
      }
    }
    return $output;
  }
```

So open `template.php` and paste the above code in it. Remember to change `phptemplate_` (in the function name in the above code) with your theme name (machine name).

Comment: Can you explain WHY "that solution did not work" for you (as in your priori comment here)?

Comment: You need to tweek it a bit for role "anonymous" ... wanna retry?

Comment: Pierre, I deleted my last comments, I was wrong --- Cocoskin's solution is not enought for me since the "Error:  The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later" problem persists. I didn't fully understand where to implement the PHP changes you mentioned... Can you please detail a bit more?

Comment: Hm, I'm happy to read your last comment above. I didn't want to indicate so before, but I already wondered before "How can the 'Disable Messages' module possibly be a solution for this?". Anyway, give me "AbitMORE" time to further refine / enhance my answer ... (I'll try somewhere later on today).

Comment: OK, your turn now to QA-test it, ok? Let me know the outcome of it ... Soon?

Comment: I did not understand - Should I paste the code in Template.TPL.PHP? And about the "is_admin/is user logged in" Where should I put this? Thanks!!!

Comment: The exact code I included in my answer should be pasted in the file named "template.php" (eg at the very end), Just don't forget to change the "phptemplate" in my sample. That file can be found in the root of the theme that you are using. And you do not need that "is_admin" anymore, because it is replaced in my pasted code with that user_is_logged_in() function. Understand?

Comment: Hi, Thank you! Because I'm having another seemingly unrelated Server-error problem in Google Webmastertools (all the pages of the site can't be accessed by Google) I talked with my server support and got to the conclusion that I should uninstall the HTTPRL+ Boost Crawler + Cache expiration submodules of Boost, and I've also reinstalled Boost; It seems that after reinstalling Boost without any code intervention whatsoever, the Error we talk about no longer appears... But I'm quite pessimistic about this error, so if I'll see it again, I will implement this solution and will update here swiftly.

Comment: I Host at a shared server, It's very problematic; It might be that this whole error message I experienced was due to "burden" on my PHP system on the shared server...

Comment: Until right this moment I was convinced that only tested-and-worked answers can be marked but I've now read the full description "Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem -OR- was the most helpful in finding your solution". You see, I did not know the rules does not necess any answer to be "surly working" but I'm glad I also became more familiar with the rules, so thank you for that also!.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module is what you need.

Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end users. The core drupal message system as offered by drupal_set_message is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users. However not all drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages sent out by drupal core and all modules to their users. This module gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out messages shown to the end users.

**Features**

- Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
- Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
- Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from
  any role.
- Disable all filtering for specific users.
- Disable all filtering for specific paths.
- Apply filtering only for specific paths.
- Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the
  end users.

**-- HOW DOES IT WORKS? --**
1. install and enable the **[Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages)** module
2. Go to "/admin/config/development/disable-messages", and check the "Enable filtering"
3. Go to "/admin/people/permissions", and give the permission who should "View status messages", "View warning messages", View error messages", and "Exclude from message filtering" if desired.

**-- Updated July 31st 2015, 2:23pm --**
**CSS trick**
to not display for anonymous user(not login)

```
body.not-logged-in div.messages.error { display: none; }
```

to not display for logged in user(***you should not do this for admin user, but here is the trick***)

```
body.logged-in div.messages.error { display: none; }
```

Comment: Cocoskin, Your answer helped me very much, this was exactly what I need - I knew the module you mentioned, it was already installed in my site, but I did not know that the action itself is done from the permissions mechanism. BUT, now I remain with one last problem, the heading <H1>ERROR</H1> and it's underlying <p> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</p> still appear (I've uploaded an image that displays this situation, please see upwards). This is problematic because it keeps alive the aesthetic problem in the site --->

Comment: CSS is not an option to treat this secondary <H1 ERROR><P Message> problem I described one comment above, since even in DOM there isn't anything suitable for "Display: none" (please see second image)...

Comment: @benous you should find out what causing that error. The css trick should work in this situation. See my update.

Comment: I am sorry @CocoSkin... :\ The error still appear (without the red notification)... I've tried to play with the CSS you mentioned a bit but without change... Can you suggest something else? Ben.

Comment: @benous the CSS trick I provided is based on your screenshot with Developer Tool. The new error message you mentioned may different. You should find out what causing that error first.

Comment: For now, I've no idea.